# Previous Activity does not come on pressing back button

Tags: android, activity-stack

I am calling one activity from another using following code.

```
if(position==4) {
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setClass(tlActivity, Income.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
}
```

but when i am into the second activity which is called. i can not return to previous activity from which activity 2 was called. is there any way i could return to the first activity by pressing back button.
i am using 2.2 SDK

thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you calling `finish()`? That is inhibiting the behavior.

Answer (score 7):

It's because you are calling `finish()`. Take that line out if you want to be able to return to it.